# Else statement with nested if

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

Am I correct in assuming that when the first if statement and nested if within the else statement both fail, I then go back up to the first for loop and increment `i` by 1?

So I can continue until j < totalCols fails even though neither the if or else statement are executing?

```
var rowCount = [];
for (var i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) {
   rowCount[i]="";
   spaceCount = 0;

   for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
      if (puzzle[i][j] == "#") { // if this fails?
         spaceCount++;
         if (j == totalCols-1) rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
      } else {
         if (spaceCount > 0) { //and this fails?
            rowCount[i] += spaceCount + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            spaceCount = 0;
         } 
      }    
   }

}
```

Comment: So I can continue until j < totalCols fails even though neither the if or else statement are executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if either of those `if` statements fails, you are still in the inner loop that is incrementing `j`. In order to get out of the inner loop you need to use the `break` statement.

Comment: Justin, so I can continue until j < totalCols fails even though neither the if or else statement are executing?

Comment: Justin, I'm sorry but now I am confused by your second comment. How can either statements execute if they both returns false? Such as when (puzzle[i][j] == "#") return false, and (spaceCount > 0) returns false as well? FYI... I am very new, and have only ever seen cases where there is a default statement.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you first finish looping through the second loop and thus increment the j.

```
    for (var j = 0; j < totalCols; j++) {
```

Only once you're done with that loop, do you go back to the 1st and increment the i.

Answer (score 0):

If the  `if` statement fails the nested `if` won't execute. It goes to the `else` block and the loop continues until the condition `i < totalRows` is met.

If the  `if` statement passes and the nested `if` fails, the loop still continues until `i < totalRows` is met.

If both if statements passes the loop continues the condition until i < totalRows is met.

What I am saying in essence is the if statement in the nested loop has nothing to do with the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the break statement to achieve this behavior.
edit: should have read the answers first.